# Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -resize

Tags: node.js, npm, gm

```
const express = require('express');

const multer = require('multer');

var fs = require('fs')
  , gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
  
const router = express.Router();


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './public/images')
    }, 
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + '.png')
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express'
    })
});

router.post('/', upload, (req, res, next) => {
    gm(req.file.path)
    .resize(240, 240)
    .gravity('Center')
    .extent(240, 240)
    .noProfile()
    .write('./public/images/update/' + req.file.originalname + '-' + Date.now(), function(err){
        console.log('err', err);
    })
})


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: are you sure about the syntax you're using? cause docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick shows otherwise.

Comment: i'm here using just multer and gm to resize an image and in using gm i have to install  GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick [npmjs.com/package/gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) and i installed imagemagick but the error is still appearing

Comment: Are you using windows? from a little bit of research, it seems that the problem is convert.exe. Try placing your ImageMagick path variable before the system32 variable in your environment variables.

Comment: instead of messing path variables, I would suggest you use sharp package. It does not have any external dependency. https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp. It's just a suggestion unless you must have to use gm for some reason.